# Type mismatch error when macro is used with a 64 bit machine

Tags: vba, 32bit-64bit, type-mismatch

I inherited a macro embedded in a chart of accounts.  It works great when used on a 32 bit machine.  64 bit machines are slowly being rolled out and a user is having trouble with the macro on a 64 bit machine.  The users presses a search button to display a pop-up window.  They enter the account number and press the "find" button and it takes them to the first instance of what they entered.  If they push "find" again, it takes them to the 2nd instance and so on.

I know I had to enter "ptrsafe" in each declaration and I have already done that.  However, we are now getting a type mismatch error on the MsgBoxEx function.  The "AddressOf zWindowProc" is highlighted in this function.

Can anyone help with what needs to be changed?  Thanks for your help.........

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum ePosMsgBox
    eTopLeft
    eTopRight
    eTopCentre
    eBottomLeft
    eBottomRight
    eBottomCentre
    eCentreScreen
    eCentreDialog
End Enum

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal zlhHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long

Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE = (-6)
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
Private Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
Private Const WH_CBT = 5

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias "SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Long, ByVal uParam As Long, lpvParam As Any, ByVal fuWinIni As Long) As Long

Private zlhHook As Long
Private zePosition As ePosMsgBox

Function MsgboxEx(Prompt As String, Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle, Optional Title, Optional HelpFile, Optional Context, Optional Position As ePosMsgBox) As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim lhInst As Long
    Dim lThread As Long

    lhInst = GetWindowLong(GetForegroundWindow, GWL_HINSTANCE)
    lThread = GetCurrentThreadId()
    zlhHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf zWindowProc, lhInst, lThread)

    zePosition = Position

    MsgboxEx = MsgBox(Prompt, Buttons, Title, HelpFile, Context)
End Function

Private Function zWindowProc(ByVal lMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Dim tFormPos As RECT, tMsgBoxPos As RECT, tScreenWorkArea As RECT
    Dim lLeft As Long, lTop As Long
    Static sbRecursive As Boolean

    If lMsg = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
        On Error Resume Next
        tScreenWorkArea = ScreenWorkArea
        GetWindowRect GetForegroundWindow, tFormPos
        GetWindowRect wParam, tMsgBoxPos

        Select Case zePosition
        Case eCentreDialog
            lLeft = (tFormPos.Left + (tFormPos.Right - tFormPos.Left) / 2) - ((tMsgBoxPos.Right - tMsgBoxPos.Left) / 2)
            lTop = (tFormPos.Top + (tFormPos.Bottom - tFormPos.Top) / 2) - ((tMsgBoxPos.Bottom - tMsgBoxPos.Top) / 2)

        Case eCentreScreen
            lLeft = ((tScreenWorkArea.Right - tScreenWorkArea.Left) - (tMsgBoxPos.Right - tMsgBoxPos.Left)) / 2
            lTop = ((tScreenWorkArea.Bottom - tScreenWorkArea.Top) - (tMsgBoxPos.Bottom - tMsgBoxPos.Top)) / 2

        Case eTopLeft
            lLeft = tScreenWorkArea.Left
            lTop = tScreenWorkArea.Top

        Case eTopRight
            lLeft = tScreenWorkArea.Right - (tMsgBoxPos.Right - tMsgBoxPos.Left)
            lTop = tScreenWorkArea.Top

        Case eTopCentre
            lLeft = ((tScreenWorkArea.Right - tScreenWorkArea.Left) - (tMsgBoxPos.Right - tMsgBoxPos.Left)) / 2
            lTop = tScreenWorkArea.Top


        Case eBottomLeft
            lLeft = tScreenWorkArea.Left
            lTop = tScreenWorkArea.Bottom - (tMsgBoxPos.Bottom - tMsgBoxPos.Top)

        Case eBottomRight
            lLeft = tScreenWorkArea.Right - (tMsgBoxPos.Right - tMsgBoxPos.Left)
            lTop = tScreenWorkArea.Bottom - (tMsgBoxPos.Bottom - tMsgBoxPos.Top)

        Case eBottomCentre
            lLeft = ((tScreenWorkArea.Right - tScreenWorkArea.Left) - (tMsgBoxPos.Right - tMsgBoxPos.Left)) / 2
            lTop = tScreenWorkArea.Bottom - (tMsgBoxPos.Bottom - tMsgBoxPos.Top)

        End Select

        If lLeft < 0 And sbRecursive = False Then
            sbRecursive = True
            zePosition = eCentreScreen
            zWindowProc HCBT_ACTIVATE, wParam, lParam
            sbRecursive = False
            Exit Function
        End If

        SetWindowPos wParam, 0, lLeft, lTop, 10, 10, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_NOACTIVATE

        UnhookWindowsHookEx zlhHook
    End If
    zWindowProc = False

End Function

Function ScreenWorkArea() As RECT
    Dim tScreen As RECT
    Dim lRet As Long
    Const SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48

    lRet = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, vbNull, tScreen, 0)
    ScreenWorkArea = tScreen
End Function
```

Comment: Here is a good article on this: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

Comment: Thanks....I had come across that a little while ago while I was researching this issue.  These APIs are a over my head but I'll take a look and see if I can figure it out......Thanks again for the help.......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue.  I found this link in another question in this forumn and it was a big help.  I went line by line and added the 64 bit version for each declare statement,  I also had to change a couple of variables to the 64 bit version and it's now working on either 32 bit or 64 bit machines.
http://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt

Comment: You shoud post here the final solution to help others