# I trq To convert API_MENU from 32bit to 64 bit but "Type Mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba

Hello can somone help me to apimenu appear on 64 bit?[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Zgx.png)

[address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2m1v.png)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    '// Get the UserForm Handle
    g_hForm = FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
    
    '// Create our menu
    Call CreateAPIMenu
    
    '// Work around for Windows repaint
    With Me
    
        .Height = 80 ' 250 - 45
        .Height = 120 ' Original + 19
        
    End With
    
    '// Subclass The Userform
    
    
    g_lpMyWndProc = SetWindowLong(g_hForm, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf HookWinProc)

'Label1 = Sheet3.Cells([5], [2])

End Sub

Public Function HookWinProc(ByVal hw As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

    '// Windows will handle all messages for you.
    '// It's the WM_COMMAND that is the end result of the user selecting a menu choice.
    '// Catch the WM_COMMAND message and do something......
    '// When the user selects a menu item from your menu,
    '// the command ID selected is sent to your window in the WPARAM field.
    '// This allows you to take the correct action for the command.
    If uMsg = WM_COMMAND Then
        
        '// This is where we catch the Menu selection
        DoEvents
        
        '// You need to match the case with the Menu ID number
        Call RunSettingsMacro(g_APIMacro(wParam - IDM_MU))
        
    End If
    
    '// NB:Pass all messages to the native window procedure to handle other msgs
    HookWinProc = CallWindowProc(g_lpMyWndProc, hw, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
    
End Function
```

Comment: Paste the function `Public Function HookWinProc` in a module and try again.

Comment: Function is in the modul and sub is in the userform.

Comment: Perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557610/how-to-convert-32-bit-vba-code-into-64-bit-vba-code/42557951

Comment: But you did not show us the API functions, which basically should be firstly adapted...

Comment: Result is the same. Have error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440144/type-mismatch-error-when-macro-is-used-with-a-64-bit-machine

Comment: same error appear